# How do I use THasAttributeFilter in Spring4d

Tags: delphi, attributes, spring4d

I would like to query some attributes (aka annotations) in a class I'm writing.

I can do it the complex way, but I'd like to use Spring4D instead.

It has a unit called `Reflection` that looks like it has what I need, but I don't know how to use it.

I've looked on the net, but there are no examples on how to use this unit.

I found:

```
THasAttributeFilter
```

Which looks like this:

```
  THasAttributeFilter<T: TRttiObject> = class(TMemberSpecificationBase<T>)
  private
    fAttributeClass: TAttributeClass;
  protected
    function Accept(const member: T): Boolean; override;
  public
    constructor Create(attributeClass: TAttributeClass);
  end;
```

Great, so I create a filter like so:

```
type
  Capability = (CanDoA, CanDoB);
  TCapabilities = set of Capability;

[Capabilities(CanDoA)]
TMyClass = class(TParent)
strict private
  class var fCapabilities: TCapabilities;
....
public
  property Capabilities: TCapabilities read GetCapabilities;
end;
```

I can create a HasAttributeFilter like so:

```
HasAttr:= THasAttributeFilter<TMyClass>.Create(CapabilitiesAttribute);
... ?? now what ??
```

How do I use Spring4D to test the attribute without having to write the zillions of lines that classical RTTI writing (as e.g. per Nick Hodges' book) requires?

Comment: You've got some typos in the property line that the editor won't let us change because they're apparently too trivial. You might want to edit them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Attributes can be fed with everything that can be evaluated at compile time, not just "Integers and numbers". Furthermore, Embarcadero themselves don't prefix attributes with `T`. Nobody says they "must" start with a `T`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, fixed the typo. You need to brush up on Attributes though, have a look at: http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=476

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These filters are implemented using the [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).
See also Spring.DesignPatterns.pas.

They are used when you need delegates like in the `IEnumerable<T>.Where()` method.

Here is a code snippet from Spring4D itself (Spring.Container.Builder):

```
var
  condition: TPredicate<TRttiMethod>;
  method: TRttiMethod;
  ...
begin
  condition := TMethodFilters.IsInstanceMethod
    and TMethodFilters.HasAttribute(InjectAttribute)
    and not TMethodFilters.HasParameterFlags([pfOut, pfVar])
    and not TMethodFilters.IsConstructor;
  for method in model.ComponentType.Methods.Where(condition) do
    ...
```

You can see that different specifications can be combined with boolean logic to form one expression: method has to be an instance method and has to have the InjectAttribute, must not have out or var paramaters and should not be a constructor.

This combined specification can then be assigned to a `TPredicate<T>` which can then be passed to the Where method.

The `TSpecification<T>` which is returned by each of the TMethodFilters is a record with operator overloading which makes the boolean logic and assigning it to a `TPredicate<T>` possible.

Using the specification pattern leads to very readable and composable code because you keep everything separated. The looping does not get cluttered with the internals how to determine if its a constructor or what kinds of parameters the method has because every specification is encapsulated into its own class.

P.S. `Methods` is a property from the `TRttiTypeHelper` from Spring.Helpers which returns `IEnumerable<TRttiMethod>`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, The TPredicate usage does look really cool. I assume it works because of the parameter capturing that's happening in the anonymous methods? I.e. this will not work in D7, but will in XE.

Comment: Yes, in all versions that are supported by Spring4D (2010 and up).